# Why is the semicolon at the end of the init-statement within the for statement mandatory?

Tags: c++, syntax

This is how the C++17 standard defines the for statement:

```
for ( init-statement conditionₒₚₜ ; expressionₒₚₜ  ) statement
```

I've also looked in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for:

```
attr(optional) for ( init-statement condition(optional) ; iteration_expression(optional) ) statement
```

Therefore, I can only understand that init-statement isn't optional when using a for loop. In other words, one has to initialize some variable inside the header in order to work with this flow of control mechanism. Well, this doesn't seem to be the case, because when I type code such as

```
for (; a != b; ++a)
```

Presuming that I have already defined these variables, it runs just fine. Not only did I not declare a variable in the header, but also referenced other variables previously defined outside the loop. If I were to provide an init-statement, its object would only be usable inside the for loop, but it seems I can use variables declared elsewhere just fine.

Having come to this conclusion, I thought I didn't need the first part: tried removing the semicolon to make it more readable (and well, just for the heck of it). It won't compile now. Compiler says it expected a `;`, calculates `a != b` as if it weren't inside a for loop: *"C4552: '!=': result of expression not used"* and finally concludes: *"C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ')'"*.

You don't need an init-statement, but you do need the semicolon. Why didn't these resources I cited initially made this clear, or is it implied in some way I am blind to?

Comment: `;` is a valid init-statement

Comment: `;` on its own is a statement in its own right. An init-statement _is_ required, but it can be a trivial one. This explicitly mentioned in the reference you linked: _"init-statement - either an expression statement (which may be a null statement "`;`"), [or] a simple declaration. . . Note that any init-statement must end with a semicolon `;`, which is why it is often described informally as an expression or a declaration followed by a semicolon."_

Comment: "removing the semicolon to make it more readable" - it doesn't make it more readable. It makes it _instantly confusing_ to people who have to write normal `for` loops every day for years.

Comment: "Why didn't these resources I cited initially made this clear, or is it implied in some way I am blind to?" - **think about how a parser or grammar definition works**. Requiring a fixed number of semicolons makes everything about writing a parser simpler; whereas by allowing optional semicolons you add unnecessary complexity into the rules of the language, and adding complexity for little-gain is _not_ something we (as programmers) assume a language-designer will do. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: Think of it this way - if you omitted the `init-statement` and the trailing semicolon, then the compiler would try to parse the provided `condition` as if it were the `init-statement` and fail. So it needs the semicolon to differentiate between an `init-statement` and a `condition`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semicolon is mandatory because `init-statement` includes the semicolon.

Quote from [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 6.5 Iteration statements:

> ```
> for (for-init-statement condition_{opt}; expression_{opt}) statement
>
> for-init-statement:
>     expression-statement
>     simple-declaration
> ```

6.2 Expression statement:

> ```
> expression-statement:
>     expression_{opt} ;
> ```

7 Declarations:

> ```
> simple-declaration:
>     decl-specifier-seq_{opt} init-declaratior-list_{opt} ;
>     attribute-specifier-seq decl-specifier-seq_{opt} init-declarator-list ;
> ```

Answer (score 4):

If you look up *init-statement* and trace through [the possibilities](https://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#iteration-statement) you'll find that they all require a trailing semi-colon.

> iteration-statement:
>     `for` `(` for-init-statement conditionₒₚₜ `;` expressionₒₚₜ `)` statement
>
> for-init-statement:
>     expression-statement
>     simple-declaration
>
> expression-statement:
>     expressionₒₚₜ `;`
>
> simple-declaration:
>     attribute-specifier-seqₒₚₜ decl-specifier-seqₒₚₜ init-declarator-listₒₚₜ `;`

A *for-init-statement* is either an *expression-statement* or a *simple-declaration*. An *expression-statement* has an optional expression but a mandatory semi-colon. Similarly, a *simple-declaration*'s components are all optional except for the final semi-colon.

Answer (score 3):

> Why didn't these resources I cited initially made this clear, or is it implied in some way I am blind to?

**Language Standard**

The first resource you cited is the C++17 standard. The language standard is written to be precise and consistent. Often (as in your case) details are deferred to other sections so that each definition appears only once, no matter how often it is used. Ease of reading by the casual coder is not a priority. The first sentence of the standard sets the scope of the document.

> This document specifies requirements for implementations of the C++ programming language.

Note who the requirements are for. They are for *implementations*, which are more commonly, yet imprecisely, called "compilers". The standard is not written for those writing C++ programs; it is written for those writing C++ compilers (and the other parts of the implementation). That is why this resource is not concerned about making points clear to a programmer's perspective.

**cppreference.com**

Coders often have to do a lot of interpretation to extract what they need from the standard. That is why there are books teaching the language and resources like your second citation, cppreference.com. Contrast the standard's stated purpose with [that of cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:FAQ):

> Our goal is to provide programmers with a complete online reference for the C and C++ languages and standard libraries, i.e. a more convenient version of the C and C++ standards.

That website's target audience is programmers, rather than implementors. Hence the harsh precision of the standard has been diluted with a bit more explanation. It tries to strike a balance between rigorous correctness and readability, with a touch of empathy for the coder who needs to check a detail of some aspect of the language.

In this particular case, I think they did a reasonable job. I guess you just overlooked the explanations?
You copied the "formal syntax" line. Right after that is an "informal syntax" line that replaces the confusing `init-statement` with `declaration-or-expression(optional) ;` making it clear that the semicolon is required, but nothing need appear before it.
Right after the the syntax lines is a list of relevant definitions. The definition for `init-statement` calls out that it "may be a null statement **`;`**". Also, the definition ends with

> Note that any `init-statement` must end with a semicolon **`;`**, which is why it is often described informally as an expression or a declaration followed by a semicolon.

*Note that the definition is directly in the relevant page. This is one way the website differs in presentation from the standard. Since the website is not the ultimate authority, there is less fallout if it is inconsistent. That gives it the freedom to repeat itself and risk definitions not being identical. Case in point: the definition of `init-statement` is repeated in the [`if` statement article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) (where the `init-statement` is optional).*

Perhaps the important takeaway is to read those definitions instead of assuming you already know what the meanings are?